# How to combine 2 columns in result table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a pretty big sql query that joins (outer join) two similar queries. Each one of them returns a table in format:

```
date       | value1(q1)
-----------+-----------
05-06-2010 |   10
05-07-2017 |   12
```

And the same for the second subquery. After i join them i get a following table:

```
date       | value1(q1) | date       | value(q2)
-----------+------------+------------+--------
05-06-2010 |    10      | NULL       | NULL
05-07-2017 |    12      | NULL       | NULL
    NULL   | NULL       | 05-07-2010 | 15
    NULL   | NULL       | 01-02-2008 | 17
```

I tried wrapping everything in a `CONCAT`, but it doesn't work.

How to get result in such a form:

```
date       | value1(q1) | value(q2)
-----------+------------+-----------
05-06-2010 |    10      |    0  
05-07-2017 |    12      |   10 
07-08-2018 |    14      |   17
```

Comment: Where do 07-08-2018 and 14 come from? Why there is not 01-02-2008 from your sample data in the expected results? Do we have to guess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT [date],
SUM([value1(q1)]) AS 'value1(q1)',
SUM([value(q2)]) AS 'value(q2)'
FROM
(
    SELECT [date],
    [value1(q1)] AS 'value1(q1)', 
    0 AS 'value(q2)' 
    FROM your_table_1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [date],
    0 AS 'value1(q1)', 
    [value(q2)] AS 'value(q2)'
    FROM your_table_2
)A
GROUP BY [date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(q1.date, q2.date) as date,
       coalesce(q1.value, 0) as value1,
       coalesce(q2.value, 0) as value2
from q1 full join
     q2
     on q1.date = q2.date;
```